# How to sort nested Datas on a Mongoose Model?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I spent around 2h trying to figure out what was wrong here...

I am trying to sort an array, by `desc asc` about a number of "points", so i called `MyDoc.Members.sort(function(a, b) { return b.points - a.points; });`

and it did'nt worked, i `stringify` my Document, copy/paste and apply the same "sort script" on the chrome console, works perfectly, i try it on a node shell, also works as expected, but in my code, it just order the things in a "weird" way.

The only difference is i work on a `Mongoose Model` so i guess the `sort` method we call on a document nested data ihas been override from the native javascript one...?

If yes, would you know how could we call the javascript native `sort method` by Array.prototype or other tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`toObject`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) on your mongoose model instance to turn it into a plain object you can manipulate:

```
var doc = MyDoc.toObject();
doc.Members.sort(function(a, b) { return b.points - a.points; });
```